# Bootstrap grid cell height breaks wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a responsive form using Bootstrap, but "cell" (Bootstrap grid element) heights are breaking the row alignment.  And since this is supposed to be responsive, I don't think I can define `<div class="row">` to force a new row (since I don't know what the rows will be).

In most instances the input height is greater than the label and there is no issue, but if the label wraps onto the second line, it's height becomes greater than the input, and the next row of grid elements starts from there.

Is there a way around this?  I've searched and only found fixed-height rows (and sometimes called fixed-height columns), but those seem to be hacks and not universally supported by browsers.  Surely there is a Bootstrap way to do this that I haven't found.

**Sorry**, the provided snipped doesn't break in the demo frame, it needs to be run full screen.  Resize the browser to see it break at most sizes, and work in a small subset (exactly the size of the snippet output).

```css
/*
  Fugly border to clearly illustrate the problem
*/
label {
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 control-label text-right" for="Field1">Long label text goes here:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="Field1" placeholder="Field1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 control-label text-right" for="Field2">Short label:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="Field2" placeholder="Field2" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 control-label text-right" for="Field3">Short label:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-lg-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="Field3" placeholder="Field3" type="text" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some common mistake in code and my solution is as follows:

1. Never use grid system in **label** or **input** class. i.e col-lg-* or col-sm-* or col-xs-* all must be written inside **div** which is parent to **label** and **input**. (For more info view my code).
2. Added a **class="row"** after class="container" just to make it proper align in terms of browser view.
3. For height of an element to be properly aligned you need to add bootstrap **class="clearfix"**.
4. Add the **class="clearfix visible-xs"** if you have problem of height in **mobile view**, or add **class="clearfix visible-sm"** if you have problemof height in **small view** and so on.
5. I have added first **clearfix visible-xs** after the total of **col-xs** becomes **12**
6. Next **clearfix visible-sm** is added after the total of **col-sm** becomes **12**.
7. finally added **clearfix visible-md**, since **col-md** is not written but it was still showing problem in **medium devices** so i needed to put that after **col-sm** immediately.

So below is my working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>TechGenium</title>

        <!-- Font-Awesome CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Field1">Long label text goes here:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Field1" placeholder="Field1" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Field3">Short label:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Field2" placeholder="Field2" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Field3">Short label:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Field3" placeholder="Field3" type="text" runat="server"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect @Niraj, `clearfix` is what I was looking for.  I had read the documents so many times, and still I missed the section [Responsive Column Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets).
And thanks for explaining a few extra issues.  I had noticed that the `col-*` classes didn't work with inputs, and found that they needed to be wrapped in `div`s, but I didn't realise that `label` should also be wrapped in a `div`.